# Objective C GCD increases CPU usage

Tags: objective-c

Recently we upgraded our code to use GCD queues. We are seeing an increase in the CPU usage (50% in old, 150% in new). When we did a Time Profiler, we see that major difference lies with the CPU utilisation by "com.apple.libdispatch-manager" thread. I assume this is the thread that interacts with the kernel events and manages dispatch queues.

Is it an expected change?

Answer (score 1):

The change is expected if your new GCD code results in better/more parallel execution of code. However, if you create *a lot* of small/fast executing blocks you might actually be wasting cycles (thread management vs. actual work done) and you might want to rethink your design.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me is there any way to control the activities done by com.apple.libdispatch-manager?

Comment: No, you cannot (AFAIK). But you control what it's doing indirectly via the `dispatch_*` functions ;-) That's what I meant when I said that you might want to rethink your design: can you do your design with fewer scheduled blocks (thus fewer scheduling work, thus fewer load on the dispatch manager).

Comment: Yes i can do that and it improves CPU usage as well but isn't this a limitation of GCD? Or is it how GCD had been designed to reduce the number of process idling and wake-ups thereby minimizing the number of times the CPU is forced to perform the relatively power-costly operation of entering and exiting idle states (time coalescing).

Comment: GCD tries to minimize thread creation/destruction (which is expensive), it thus _dispatches_ your blocks to existing threads if possible. I imagine that if you hammer it with a lot of blocks there's simply a lot of management to do and the management suddenly becomes a bottleneck (but I'm not a GCD expert so don't know for sure).

Comment: Also, GCD does limit the number of simultaneous threads it's using (IIRC there is a limit per process).